# execute php on web page button click

Tags: javascript, php, action

I have to execute a shell script when pressing a button on a web page.
For this I'm using php so I have created a button in the file test.php

```
<form method="get" action="buildMaster.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Build Master" id="btnMaster">
</form>
```

when pressing the button, the php buildMaster.php is called:

```
<?php
    shell_exec('touch /Users/testUser/xxx');
?>
```

To test, I just touch a file to see if the script is called but nothing happens.
The browser (Safari on Mac Lion) goes to buildMaster.php but nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: print the shell_exec() output and check what you are getting

Comment: Write any static html content in buildMaster.php and test it

Comment: I guess I have to add "$output = shell_exec(...)" to the php, but how do I see the output ? I've never worked with web/php before. Once the action has been called, where do I check the output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out. I have to redirect stderr to stdout.

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('touch /Users/testUser/xxx 2>&1');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

The output:
touch: .... Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

And you'll see the output of your command

Also look to documentation: https://www.php.net/shell_exec - this function might be disabled if PHP is running in save mode.

Comment: Ok, ls writes the list of files to the browser so the php actually works. But the touch does nothing and outputs nothing.

Comment: Touch command outputs nothing in the shell. Check if the file is created or its timestamp has changed on webserver.